# Branches of $\log(z^2)$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

Suppose $z=x+iy$, then $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\theta_p=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac y x\right)$, so we have
$$z=re^{i\theta},\theta=\theta_p+2n\pi$$
Now, $z^2=x^2-y^2+i(2xy)$, so $r'=x^2+y^2$ and $\theta_p'=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2xy}{x^2-y^2}\right)$, so we have
$$z^2=(x^2+y^2)e^{i\theta'},\theta'=\theta_p'+2n\pi$$
Hence,
$$\log(z)=\log(r)+i\theta_p+2n\pi i$$
$$\log(z^2)=\log(r^2)+i\theta_p'+2n\pi i\tag 1$$
but in my homework solution,
$$\log(z^2)=\log(r^2)+i2\theta_p+2n\pi i\tag 2$$
So from $(1)$ and $(2)$ we have,
$$\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2xy}{x^2-y^2}\right)=2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac y x\right)$$
But I don't think that this equality should be true?

Comment: so your problem is how to define the  imaginary part  of $\log(z^2)$ ? personally I don't care of $\tan^{-1}$, I write $\log(r e^{i \theta}) = \log(r) + i\theta$ for every $r \in ]0,\infty[, \ \theta \in ]-\pi,\pi]$. changing of branch means only changing the domain of definition of $\theta$ (i.e. of $Im(\log(z))$) : for example $\log(r e^{i \theta}) = \log(r) + i\theta$ for every $(r,\theta) \in \ ]0,\infty[ \ \times \ [2 \pi,4\pi[$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}&\color{red}{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\arctan\frac{2xy}{x^2-y^2}\right)}=\frac{2y(x^2-y^2)-4x^2y}{(x^2-y^2)^2}\frac1{1+\frac{4x^2y^2}{(x^2-y^2)^2}}=\frac{-2y}{(x^2+y^2)}\\
&\color{green}{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(2\arctan\frac yx\right)}=\frac{-2\frac y{x^2}}{1+\frac{y^2}{x^2}}=\frac{-2y}{x^2+y^2}\end{align*}$$

Fill in details.

Comment: May I ask what is this?

Comment: @user302007 You know, I'm sure, from real analysis that if two differentiable functions $\;f,g\;$ fulfill $\;f'(x)=g'(x)\;$ for $\;x\in(a,b)\;$ , then $\;f(x)=g(x)+k\;,\;\;k$ a constant, in that interval,  right? Then substituting for some value you can find the value of the constant.  Well, the above shows this happens for your arctangents with respect to the variable  $\;x\;$.